# Creating tables using Doctrine in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2

After I had created a "motor" DB in MySQL, I configured the DB in Symfony with this command:

```
$ php symfony configure:database "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=motor" root <mypassword>
```

Under `appname/config/doctrine/` I have a `schema.yml` file.

In this file I defined the following table:

```
Car:
  actAs: { Timestampable: ~ }
  columns: 
    brand: { type: string(255), notnull: true }
    model: { type: string(255), notnull: true }
    version: { type: string(255), notnull: true }
    url: { type: string(255), notnull: true }
    year: { type: string(4), notnull: true }
    info: { type: string(10000), notnull: true }
    updated_at: { type: timestamp, notnull: true }
    created_at: { type: timestamp, notnull: true }
```

Then I executed the command:

```
$ php symfony doctrine:build --model
```

Which gave me the following output:

```
>> doctrine  generating model classes
>> file+     /tmp/doctrine_schema_57936.yml
>> tokens    /home/username/webapps/www/appname/lib/model/doctrine/CarTable.class.php
>> tokens    /home/username/webapps/www/appname/lib/model/doctrine/Car.class.php
>> tokens    /home/username/webapps/www/appname/lib/model/doctrine/base/BaseCar.class.php
>> autoload  Resetting application autoloaders
>> file-     /home/username/webapps/www/appname/cache/frontend/dev/config/config_autoload.yml.php
```

After that I proceeded to generate the sql with this command:

```
$ php symfony doctrine:build --sql
```

The output is:

```
>> doctrine  generating model classes
>> file+     /tmp/doctrine_schema_89541.yml
>> tokens    /home/username/webapps/www/motor/lib/model/doctrine/base/BaseCar.class.php
>> autoload  Resetting application autoloaders
>> file-     /home/username/webapps/www/motor/cache/frontend/dev/config/config_autoload.yml.php
>> doctrine  generating sql for models
>> doctrine  Generated SQL successfully for models
```

However under `appname/data/sql/` the file `schema.sql` generated is empty.

So this command `$ php symfony doctrine:insert-sql`, didn't generated any table in my DB. However it gave a successful message output:

```
>> doctrine  creating tables
>> doctrine  created tables successfully
```

The command `$ php symfony doctrine:build --all`, didn't work either.

Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have an error using `doctrine:build --all` ? And what is the output of `doctrine:build --sql` ?

Comment: I have updated the question with `doctrine:build --sql` output. About `doctrine:build --all`it doesn't give me any errors.

Comment: Sorry I mean, the output of `insert-sql`.

Comment: Just updated again the question with the `$ php symfony doctrine:insert-sql`output.

Comment: Where is the output of the above command?

Comment: This is strange. I did the same and I got my `schema.sql` filled. Have you tried to remove the `schema.sql` and relaunch `build --sql`? Also, check file/folder permissions.

Comment: It seems that there was something wrong with this Symfony installation. I've downloaded again Symfony and this same code worked like a charm. Thanks for the help anyways.

Comment: Great, could you answer your own question and mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there was nothing wrong with the methodology I was using in order to do this.

The problem resided in the Symfony version I was using, which for some reason wasn't working correctly.

In order to fix it I downloaded the latest Symfony 1.4.18 version and run the code again, this time it worked properly.